# How to Create cloud service with Ubuntu OS on Microsoft azure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure

I have a PHP application which runs on Ubuntu.

I am looking for Cloud service on Azure which has Ubuntu OS so I can deploy my application over there.

I am able to find WAMP (Windows + Apache + My SQL + PHP) Cloud service on Azure but I am looking for LAMP (Linux + Apache + My SQL + PHP).

Appreciate for Any help.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about **Azure Virtual Machines** rather than Azure Cloud Services, which are two different compute options. You can check [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/) to get the details about the different compute options on Azure. 
Cloud Services are a Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS) concept and only run on Windows Server. Azure Virtual Machines are basically hosting of VMs and these come in both **Linux and Windows Server**.
You can find ready-made Ubuntu-based VM images containing the LAMP stack in the [Azure Marketplace](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/?term=lamp)  or you can check the [VM Depot](https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/List/Index?sort=Featured&search=lamp+platform%3A%3Dubuntu+), which contains community-provided VM images.
Alternatively, you can prep your own Virtual Machine and save it as a VM image, which you can then use to create new VMs off of it.

Comment: Not sure I get what you're after. SaaS is just an incarnation of hosting an application on IaaS or PaaS. Your users would perceive your website as SaaS, but you're hosting it on either PaaS or SaaS. If you're referring to Azure Web Apps, which are also PaaS but a specialized form, then these are only provided on Windows and IIS.

Comment: Nick this is same as we deploy our .net application on Cloud service (Window OS and IIS server) I need to deploy my PHP application on Cloud service ( Ubuntu OS and Apache Server) . so I just need to know is there any way to deploy this as cloud service or I have to go with Virtual machine option. sorry for confusion.

Comment: Nick in short I am looking for PaaS not for IaaS option.

Comment: Azure Cloud Services are Windows only. Depending on your timeframe, you may want to start looking at Azure Service Fabric (currently in preview), which will have support for Linux in the future (http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/20/announcing-azure-service-fabric-reducing-complexity-in-a-hyper-scale-world/).

Comment: Now I think of it, an alternative solution would be to leverage Docker on Azure and use Swarm to scale across multiple machines. Is this something you've looked into?

Comment: I am not aware of Docker on Azure. I will look at this.. will this be cheaper then Virtual Machine and Provide auto scalability.

Comment: Not necessarily cheaper but it provides isolation of your application on top of VMs. With a project such as Docker Swarm you can then scale across multiple machines. Note that with Azure VMs you can also perform auto-scaling, see here for info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/

Comment: Thanks Nick for valuable thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Cloud Services (worker and web roles) are Windows only.  Virtual Machines can be Windows or Linux.

However, if you are just looking to host your web front end you could use an Azure Web App (previously named Azure Websites) which has first class support for PHP, but the underling OS is still Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from Nick Trough you might want to try an ARM Template, e.g. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/b1908e74259da56a92800cace97350af1f1fc32b/lamp-app

This allows you to deploy a simple LAMP server (like marketplace or VM Depot) but has the added benefit of providing the configuration as an ARM Template (i.e. code) so you can easily modify it.